# Trivials are not easy to prove.

Tags: real-analysis

If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\neq y$, then show that there are neighborhoods $N_x$ of $x$ and $N_y$ of $y$ shuch  that $N_x \cap N_y=\emptyset.$

I know the result is trivial but trivial things are not easy to prove. I just want to see what the formal proof look like.

Answer (score 5):

$d(x,y)=\delta>0$

What can you say about  $B(x,\frac{\delta}{3})$ and $B(y,\frac{\delta}{3})$...

Comment: So, can you show me how is this going to be a formal proof?

Comment: I have given sufficient hints.... Spend some time on this and the ask me..

Comment: Why negative votes??

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume $x \neq y$. Hence, their distance is some number, say $r>0$: $|x-y|=r$. $\mathbf{Choose } $ $\epsilon_1 = \frac{r}{4} $ and $\epsilon_2 = \frac{r}{4} $. We claim $B(x, \epsilon_1) \cap B(y, \epsilon_2) = \varnothing $. To reach contradiction, we can assume the opposite, so we suppose there is an element in this intersection: $z \in B(x, \epsilon_1) \cap B(y, \epsilon_2)$. In particular, we have $|z-x| < \epsilon_1$ and $|z-y|<\epsilon_2$. Next,

$$ r = |x-y| \leq |x-z| + |z-y| < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 = \frac{r}{2}$$

Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \ne y$. Without loss of generality, assume $x<y$. 

Let $ \epsilon =\frac{ y-x}{2}$ 
Take $N_x = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon )$ and $N_y = (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon )$. Then $N_x$ and $N_y$ are neighborhoods containing $x$ and $y$ respectively.

To show $N_x \cap N_y = \varnothing$:

Suppose not. Then $z \in N_x \cap N_y$.  
\begin{alignat}{}
z \in N_x \Rightarrow z \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon ) \Rightarrow z< x + \epsilon \\
z \in N_y \Rightarrow z \in (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon ) \Rightarrow z> y - \epsilon && \\ \Rightarrow y- \epsilon < z < x+ \epsilon && \\ \Rightarrow y- \epsilon < x+ \epsilon && \\ \Rightarrow y-x <2 \epsilon  &&  \\ \Rightarrow \frac{y-x}{2} <\epsilon
\end{alignat}
which contradicts the definition of $\epsilon$.